# Buy X Get Y Logic problem happening after adding an item with the same id that belongs to the same array in the database

Tags: laravel-10

I have a problem in my Laravel code. I am making a discount method that is like buy x get y that Shopify has, but I am having a problem. First I am going to explain the offer, the offer is buy two items and the third one in the cart when you add it it will be discounted.

Here is my xyoffer model that has the data:

```
class Xyoffer extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'description',
        'type',
        'rule',
        'buy_model_type',
        'buy_models',
        'buy_items',
        'buy_amount',
        'get_model_type',
        'get_models',
        'get_items',
        'get_amount',
        'discount_percentage',
        'discount_amount',
        'status',
    ];
    protected $casts = [
        'buy_models' => 'array',
        'buy_items' => 'array',
        'get_items' => 'array',
        'get_models' => 'array',
    ]; 
}
```

The offer that I stored is buy two get one. Now, it is working well when the items are different and when I only add three items, one is getting the discount and two are normal. The problem happens when I add one more item (note: this only happen if the `shopify_product_id` is in the `buy_items` and the `get_items`, if they are not it works fine). When adding one more, which means that the total quantity of the items that can be used is four the offer is canceled and all the items are back to there original state. How can I fix this?

This is the code that is making the discount:

```
class XyOfferAction
{
use AsAction;

    public function handle($cart)
    {
        DB::beginTransaction();
    
        try {
            // Reset all items in the cart to their normal state
            $this->removeInvalidDiscounts($cart);
    
            // Fetch all active offers
            $offers = XyOffer::all();
    
            // Apply each offer to the cart
            foreach ($offers as $offer) {
                $this->applyOffer($cart, $offer);
            }
    
            // Consolidate cart items after applying offers
            $this->consolidateCartItems($cart);
    
            // Commit the transaction
            DB::commit();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            // Rollback the transaction in case of any errors
            DB::rollBack();
            throw $e;
        }
    }

    protected function removeInvalidDiscounts(Cart $cart)
    {
        // Load cart items to ensure we're working with the latest data
        $cart->load('cartItems');
    
        // Reset all items to their normal price and remove any discount flags
        foreach ($cart->cartItems as $item) {
            $item->price = $item->compare_at; // Assume compare_at holds the normal price
            $item->total_price = $item->price * $item->quantity;
            $item->is_discounted = false; // Reset the discount flag
            $item->save();
        }
    
        // Update the cart's totals after resetting prices
        $cart->updateTotals();
    }

    protected function applyOffer(Cart $cart, XyOffer $offer)
    {
        $buyItemIds = $offer->buy_items;
        $getItemIds = $offer->get_items;
    
        // Retrieve the 'buy' items from the cart
        $buyItemsInCart = $cart->cartItems()->whereIn('shopify_product_id', $buyItemIds)->get();
        $buyQuantity = $buyItemsInCart->sum('quantity');
        
    
        // Calculate the number of offers that can be applied based on 'buy' quantity
        $offerCount = intdiv($buyQuantity, $offer->buy_amount);
    
        // If the offer is applicable
        if ($offerCount > 0) {
            // Check if the buy items and get items are the same
            $sameItemForBuyAndGet = $buyItemIds == $getItemIds;
    
            if ($sameItemForBuyAndGet) {
                // Adjust the buyQuantity to exclude the quantities used to trigger the offer
                $buyQuantity -= ($offerCount * $offer->buy_amount);
            }
    
            // Retrieve the 'get' items from the cart
            $getItemsInCart = $cart->cartItems()->whereIn('shopify_product_id', $getItemIds)->get();
    
            foreach ($getItemsInCart as $item) {
                
                // Calculate the quantity eligible for discount
                $eligibleForDiscount = $sameItemForBuyAndGet ? $buyQuantity : $item->quantity;
                // Calculate how many items can be discounted considering the already discounted ones
                $discountableQuantity = min($eligibleForDiscount, ($offerCount * $offer->get_amount));
    
                if ($discountableQuantity > 0) {
                    // Apply discount to these items
                    $this->discountItem($item, $discountableQuantity, $offer);
    
                    if ($sameItemForBuyAndGet) {
                        // Reduce the available quantity for discounting for the next iteration
                        $buyQuantity -= $discountableQuantity;
                    }
                }
    
                // Calculate any remaining 'get' items that are not eligible for discount
                $nonDiscountableQuantity = $item->quantity - $discountableQuantity;
    
                // If there are such items
                if ($nonDiscountableQuantity > 0) {
                    // Set the price for these items to their normal amount
                    $this->applyNormalPrice($item, $nonDiscountableQuantity);
                }
            }
        }
    
        // After applying all offers, update the cart's totals
        $cart->updateTotals();
    }

    protected function applyNormalPrice(CartItem $item, $nonDiscountableQuantity)
    {
        // If there's a split item, we need to update the non-discounted item's quantity and price
        if ($nonDiscountableQuantity > 0 && $item->is_discounted) {
            // Create a new CartItem for the non-discounted quantity
            $normalItem = $item->replicate();
            $normalItem->quantity = $nonDiscountableQuantity;
            $normalItem->is_discounted = false;
            $normalItem->price = $normalItem->compare_at;
            $normalItem->total_price = $normalItem->price * $nonDiscountableQuantity;
            $normalItem->save();
        }
    }

    protected function discountItem(CartItem $item, $quantityToDiscount, XyOffer $offer)
    {
        \Log::debug('Starts Discounting');
        // If we are discounting fewer items than the item's quantity
        if ($quantityToDiscount < $item->quantity) {
            // Create a new CartItem for the non-discounted quantity
            $nonDiscountedItem = $item->replicate();
            $nonDiscountedItem->quantity = $item->quantity - $quantityToDiscount;
            $nonDiscountedItem->is_discounted = false;
            $nonDiscountedItem->price = $nonDiscountedItem->compare_at;
            $nonDiscountedItem->total_price = $nonDiscountedItem->price * $nonDiscountedItem->quantity;
            $nonDiscountedItem->save();
    
            // Update the original item with the discounted quantity
            $item->quantity = $quantityToDiscount;
        }
    
        // Apply the discount to the original item
        $item->is_discounted = true;
        if ($offer->discount_percentage == 100) {
            $item->price = 0;
            $item->total_price = 0;
        } else {
            $item->price *= (1 - $offer->discount_percentage / 100);
            $item->total_price = $item->price * $item->quantity;
        }
        $item->save();
    
        // After saving the discounted item, store its information in the session
        $discountedItemInfo = [
            'shopify_product_id' => $item->shopify_product_id,
            'title'              => $item->title,
            'quantity'           => $quantityToDiscount,
            'message'            => 'You have received a discount!', // Custom message
            'in_use'             => 1,
        ];
    
        // Retrieve the existing array of discounted items from the session, or initialize a new one if it doesn't exist
        $discountedItems = session('discounted_items', []);
    
        $existingItemKey = array_search($item->shopify_product_id, array_column($discountedItems, 'shopify_product_id'));
    
        if ($existingItemKey !== false && $discountedItems[$existingItemKey]['quantity'] === $quantityToDiscount) {
            // Item exists in the session with the same quantity, do not re-add it
        } else {
            // Item does not exist or quantity has changed, add/update the item information in the session
            $discountedItems[$existingItemKey] = $discountedItemInfo;
    
            // Put the updated array back into the session
            session(['discounted_items' => $discountedItems]);
        }
    
        // \Log::info('Discounted items in session:', session('discounted_items', []));
    }

    protected function consolidateCartItems(Cart $cart)
    {
        // Group items by shopify_variant_id and is_discounted flag
        $groupedItems = $cart->cartItems()
            ->get()
            ->groupBy(function ($item) {
                return $item->shopify_variant_id . '-' . $item->is_discounted;
            });
    
        foreach ($groupedItems as $groupKey => $items) {
            // If there's more than one item in the group, consolidate them
            if ($items->count() > 1) {
                $firstItem = $items->shift(); // Keep the first item
    
                // Sum quantities and total_prices, then delete the other items
                $totalQuantity = $items->sum('quantity') + $firstItem->quantity;
                $totalPrice = $items->sum('total_price') + $firstItem->total_price;
    
                // Update the first item with the new total quantity and price
                $firstItem->quantity = $totalQuantity;
                $firstItem->total_price = $totalPrice;
                $firstItem->save();
    
                // Delete the other items
                foreach ($items as $item) {
                    $item->delete();
                }
            }
        }
    
        // Update the cart's totals after consolidation
        $cart->updateTotals();
    }
}
```